# Why does my html code work everywhere but Mailchimp?

Tags: html, mailchimp, imagemap

I have created html code for an image map and it works everywhere but Mailchimp.  I tested it on various HTML editors and works perfectly, then I paste the copy into a "Code" box on Mailchimp and my image shows up but only links back to the image URL.

My code is pasted below for review, if anyone can find my issue. THANK YOU!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FyVB5sy3y2w/VH4RqQpEP8I/AAAAAAAAAmY/lhMdhZTJIeo/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2014-12-02%2Bat%2B1.11.09%2BPM.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FyVB5sy3y2w/VH4RqQpEP8I/AAAAAAAAAmY/lhMdhZTJIeo/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2014-12-02%2Bat%2B1.11.09%2BPM.png" usemap="#Map" border="0" use map="#Map" />
<map name="Map">
<area shape="rect" coords="5,6,537,108" href="http://www.mountainstatesrosen.com/" target="_blank" alt="Home">
<area shape="rect" coords="9,111,226,339" href="http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/how-to-roast-a-lamb-michael-psilakis/1100269647?ean=9780316041218" target="_blank" alt="Book">
<area shape="rect" coords="231,110,537,304" href="http://www.mountainstatesrosen.com/store-locator/" target="_blank" alt="Lamb">
<area shape="rect" coords="346,306,537,480" href="http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=22962500&color=010&itemdescription=true&navAction=jump&search=true&isProduct=true&parentid=A_NEWARRIVALS#/" target="_blank" alt="Sheep Cups">
<area shape="rect" coords="105,341,343,503" href="http://www.americanlamb.com/store/products/sheep-cutting-board/" target="_blank" alt="Cutting ">
<area shape="rect" coords="18,507,291,703" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000CFTJB" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" alt="Meatball">
<area shape="rect" coords="303,506,535,698" href="http://www.americanlamb.com/store/products/lamb-spice-blend/" target="_blank" alt="Spice">
</map>
</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When pasting into MailChimp and checking the links. They seem to be linking to the correct places. Upon sending a test email to myself, the links still worked. Seems like something may be wrong with the template you are trying. You can use the Preview mode, the Send test email mode, and email inspector for validation.

Comment: Michael, thanks so much for getting back to me.  I actually figured it out.  I had 2 image maps on the same email named "Map". I renamed one and it worked perfectly. Beginner's mistake. :)

Comment: Really helpful @Jessicak